# How to layout beans for single page design

Tags: jsf, icefaces, javabeans, inject

Hey guys.  I'm designing a site that uses the Icefaces framework.  I've been reading a book called Real World Java EE patterns.  I'm kind of confused how to layout the pages.  Normally I would have just a POJO class implement serializable for a bean.  This bean would then back each page.  With a single page design I'm going to have a bunch of elements on the page.  Datatables, trees, inputs, calendars etc.  Is it normal or best practice to have separate beans for each datatable, calendar, etc or put that all in one bean?  I'm not sure how to approach this.  Right now each element is a bean and I'm using the @Inject annotation to have the data table talk to the tree and vise versa.  This creates really bad code and if I put this as a member of the class I will get a circular reference because the data table bean has to inject the calendar and the calendar has to inject the data table.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use a single bean per `<h:form>` or at least per view (XHTML/JSP file). Any related beans will just be injected in this particular "main" bean (and thus not among each other).

Comment: Thanks for your help!  But what if a data table bean needed to know what the tree selection value was and the tree needed to know what state the state the data table was in so it could be cleared?  I'm sorry if that doesn't make much sense.  Do you think you could point me to a good sample project.  I'm having a hard time finding something like that.  Thanks.